# BIM 360 Revit 2021 DocumentOpened Event Error

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-bim360

I have some code that is triggered by the DocumentOpened event. It will modify the parameter values of certain Family Instances (if found in the model). This code has been running successfully in Revit 2019 and 2020 - all platforms - and by that I mean local servers, Revit Server and BIM 360 2020. It runs successfully in 2021 on local servers and Revit Server, but when we open a 2021 model from BIM 360 we get errors.

The journal file reveals this:

```
' 9:< FileCheckTrigger dependencies update
' 8:< REGEN_DOC_CONTEXT_INFO: Changing wrong atom in regeneration
' 8:< FaultyAtomsCheckLog - Comparasion difference found :
'11:< MODIFICATION IS FORBIDDEN: Element modification is forbidden because it is a member of a family, and that family is not being edited.
```

Elements are typically borrowed by this process and they are relinquished by the user via the standard UI through the normal course of working in and syncing the model.

Has something changed in the way Revit 2021 models are handled in BIM 360?

2/12
I just noticed this in the journal and thought it may mean something to someone:

```
'C 12-Feb-2021 08:27:14.980;  DBG_INFO: No record for element 14845 in PermissionsCache: line 134 of D:\Ship\2021_px64\Source\DataStorage\CloudClientInterop\ModelAccessProvider\ModelPermissionAdapter.cpp.
```

This is the ID of the element my code is trying to modify.

Comment: Can you please confirm the Revit version you have? 2021.1?

Comment: I/we are using 2021.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I am discussing this case with Craig in the corresponding [Revit API discussion forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/bd-p/160) thread [BIM 360 Revit 2021 DocumentOpened Event Error](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/bim-360-revit-2021-documentopened-event-error/td-p/10041659).

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness: this issue was discussed further in the Revit API discussion thread mentioned above and resolved in the Revit 2021.1.5 Hotfix update release. The internal development ticket numbers processed and resolved were the report issue *REVIT-174829* and the code fix *REVIT-182429*.